Xunit: set env variable specifically for one test
[Fact]
public void GetStatus_WhenLocalMachine_ReturnsLocalhostValue()
{
    // Arrange
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Localhost", true);
    var service = new Service(_configuration.Object);

    // Act
    var status = service.GetStatus();
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Localhost", null);

    // Assert
    status.Hash.Should().Be(DeploymentService.Hash);
}

I have this method which works correctly only when there is env variable Localhost: true. I also have some other tests that do not work because this env variable makes them read the wrong settings. (They actually work because I am resetting this value in this test)
Is there a way to set env variable specifically for one test? And avoid resetting them?

I suspect there is nothing built in, but a collection fixture could capture the current environment, and restore  in its Dispose. Alternatively XUnit provides for extensions... there maybe something there to build from.

Hi @Deivydas Voroneckis, does it work for you to custom the BeforeAfterTestAttribute? If not, you can try to create a class that implements IDisposable, which will save the current environment variables and restore them when the test is finished.

I think it is possible to use BeforeAfterTestAttribute in xUnit, so the idea is to run some code before and after your test.
public class BeforeAfterAttribute : BeforeAfterTestAttribute
{
    public override void Before(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Localhost", true);
    }

    public override void After(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Localhost", null);
    }
}

And you can use this attribute for your specific test:
[Fact]
[BeforeAfter]
public void GetStatus_WhenLocalMachine_ReturnsLocalhostValue()
{
    // Arrange
    var service = new Service(_configuration.Object);

    // Act
    var status = service.GetStatus();

    // Assert
    status.Hash.Should().Be(DeploymentService.Hash);
}

